# Weird PE sections from cygwin-gcc generated files

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw

I have a simple program compiled with cygwin:

```
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -fPIC -I/usr/local/include *.c -o main
```

And it contains weird PE section names like `/4`:

[image]

Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: Which ones do *you* find *"weird"*, why, and what problem do you need to have solved?

Comment: @IInspectable I already mentioned in the question, `/4`

Comment: That's not even half of an answer to 3 questions asked. At that pace it'll be a while until we have uncovered your real question.

Comment: If the section name is longer than 8 characters, they are actually written into the string table, and the number after the slash is the offset into the string table.
See [PE Section Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#section-table-section-headers), the `Name` field.